# How to show a modal notification using flask framework and python?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-modal

I am working on building a web application using Flask framework and Python.
Using one of the html pages, i am getting inputs from the user and processing them once the user clicks on the `Submit` button. The requirement is that, once the user clicks on the `Submit` button, i would like to show a modal notification (or any notification) that the data is being processed.

The code for the `Submit` button in `process_data.html` is -

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
</div>
```

I tried adding modal code to it as follows -

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info", data-toggle="modal", data-target="#exampleModal") }}
</div>
```

but it failed with `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression`.

**routes.py** code -

```
@app.route("/process_data", methods=['GET','POST'])
def process_data():

    form = ProcessDataForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        posts = get_data('process_data', version=form.version.data, cn=form.cn.data, ip=form.ip.data)
        if posts:
            flash(f'Processing Complete!','success')
        else:
            flash(f'Processing failed','warning')
        return render_template('process_data.html', title='Process Data', form=form, posts=posts)   

    return render_template('process_data.html', title='Process Data', form=form)
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to replace *class* by *class_* in your form.submit method as described here: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html  in the rendering section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Message Flash.

A sample code is provided here:

```
from flask import flash

@app.route("/process_data", methods=['GET','POST'])
def process_data():

    form = ProcessDataForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Data is being processed')
        posts = get_data('process_data', version=form.version.data, cn=form.cn.data, ip=form.ip.data)
        return render_template('process_data.html', title='Process Data', form=form, posts=posts)   

    return render_template('process_data.html', title='Process Data', form=form)
```

In you html :

```
<!doctype html>
<title>My Application</title>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Please find the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/) for more explaination.

Comment: Thank you! I modified ```routes.py``` and when i tried the change you suggested, both ```Data is being processed``` & ```Processing Complete!``` are flashed at once. I want to display the first message first, then process data and then remove the first flashed message and show the new message (outcome of processing). Thanks.